# Background script run at login interrupted when I run tmux in terminal

Tags: shell-script, terminal, tmux

In `~/.profile` I run a script in the background (`redshift` for changing the screen temperature at night time).

After logging in, I can open a terminal, and run `tmux`.

However, at this point, redshift visibly gets interrupted as the screen temperature resets and it seems that redshift starts again in this terminal.

What's happening here? I get the impression that `~/.profile` is for each shell, and gets parsed again when I run tmux. Could this be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [6.2 Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), `~/.profile` is executed when you start an interactive login shell (or use the `--login` option).  Since `tmux`'s default behavior is to start a login shell in each new window, your profile is being executed again.

Probably the simplest thing to do is change your script to determine whether `redshift` is running, and start it only if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, and just for the record I edited my script [as shown here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bash-script-check-process-is-running-if-not-start-787605/#post3855893).